# How to Change Database in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I created a new project and set up my database accordingly in the `.env` file.

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=example_olddb
DB_USERNAME=example_user
DB_PASSWORD=example_password
```

After much development, I want to change my database to a new database. So I edited the '.env' file again.

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=example_newdb///<-- change here
DB_USERNAME=example_user
DB_PASSWORD=example_password
```

However, I got the following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'example_olddb'

It used to work in `Laravel 5.5` and `5.6`, but not now in `5.7`. I tried to clear the cache, but same error persists. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: clear the configuration cache with the following artisan command: `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: It looks like your .env file was not updated with the new database name. You may want to double check whether these databases exist and correct .env file was uploaded.Sometimes, due to the permission issue, file don't get overwritten.

Comment: it work. can you put it as answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: Hello @sooon what happened? Your problem is not solved?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya yes, solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After completion of `.env` edit, You can clear the configuration cache with the following artisan command: `php artisan config:cache`